# How do I enable the touchpad while typing in 16.04?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, system-settings, accessibility, onboard

Having the touchpad disabled while typing slows down my typing with onscreen keyboards like OnBoard. In 14.04 there was a setting for this in the mouse settings, but it's gone now in 16.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mouse locks when keys are pressed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42764/mouse-locks-when-keys-are-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

As the new settings manager does not have this option, you have to do it via command line.
Disabling touchpad while typing is maintained by `syndaemon`. It's started by default, but you can kill it by typing

```
killall syndaemon
```

into terminal. If you wish to do it at startup, you can put this line into you `.profile` file, `cron` or to startup applications.