# How can I disable "disable touchpad while typing" on 19.10?

Tags: touchpad, 19.10

I have a Lenovo Yoga and it disables the touchpad while typing. There are no options in the system settings to turn off this feature. How can I toggle this feature on and off? Ideally I'd like a command line solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the touchpad while typing in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772923/how-do-i-enable-the-touchpad-while-typing-in-16-04)

Comment: @K7AAY Not in view of the much clearer answer already posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line would be

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

For the graphical method

```
sudo apt install tweaks
```

and

[image]

Comment: `gsettings` rite opposed to settings in your command?

Comment: This used to be in Settings! When are they just going to include gnome-tweaks in Settings, sigh?